# Using SQL joins to determine when something is available

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data about products and services and the dates on which they are and are not available. I want to be able to produce a list of products that are available on any specified date.

The data I have assumes that products are always available by default, but that their availability can be restricted, either by specifying that they are NOT available within certain date ranges, or that they are ONLY available within certain date ranges.

The problem I am having is with the former scenario; I can't find a way to use joins to specify that if a product is within the date range of ANY of its NOT entries, then it should not appear in the results. I can't really find the words to explain this properly, so it is probably best illustrated with a simplified example...

Product table:

```
ID,Name
0,Apples  
1,Bananas  
2,Carrots  
3,Dates  
4,Eggs
```

Restriction table:

```
ID,Product_ID,Type,Start,End
0,2,Only,2014-05-20,2014-05-31  
1,2,Only,2014-07-01,2014-07-14  
2,3,Not,2014-03-05,2014-04-04  
3,3,Not,2014-04-29,2014-06-15
```

Examples of intended results:

```
Date: 2014-01-01  
Products available: Apples, Bananas, Dates, Eggs  

Date: 2014-04-04  
Products available: Apples, Bananas, Eggs

Date: 2014-05-25  
Products available: Apples, Bananas, Carrots, Eggs  

Date: 2014-07-02  
Products available: Apples, Bananas, Carrots, Dates, Eggs
```

My current attempt with a left join:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Product LEFT JOIN Restriction ON Product.ID = Restriction.ProductID  
WHERE  
    (
        Restriction.Type = 'Only'
        AND DATEDIFF(Restriction.Start, '2014-04-04') <= 0
        AND DATEDIFF(Restriction.End, '2014-04-04') >= 0
    )
    OR
    (
        Restriction.Type = 'Not'
        AND
        (
            DATEDIFF(Restriction.Start, '2014-04-04') > 0
            OR
            DATEDIFF(Restriction.End, '2014-04-04') < 0
        )
    )
    OR Restriction.Type IS NULL
```

Output from the above query:

```
Product.ID,Product.Name,Restriction.Product_ID,Restriction.Type,Restriction.Start,Restriction.End  
0,Apples,-,-,-,-,-
1,Bananas,-,-,-,-,-
3,Dates,3,3,Not,2014-04-29,2014-06-15
4,Eggs,-,-,-,-,-
```

As you can see, "Dates" still appears in the results, because although its join with restriction #2 is omitted, its join with restriction #3 is not. I can't find any way to alter the query to resolve this without breaking the logic in some other way. I do hope that I am making sense here, and that somebody can see whatever piece of insight it is to which I am currently blind.

The database software I'm using is MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Your intended results have four dates that I don't see in the data.  Where do they come from?

Comment: They're just arbitrary dates plucked out of the air. I want to be able to see which products are available on any day of the year.

Answer (score 2):

First get the ones in the restriction table that **is not** available for `now()` (you can change that to any date you like)

```
select *
  from restriction
 where (type = 'Not' and now() between start and end)
    or (type = 'Only' and now() not between start and end);
```

Now make that part a `left outer join` and use all rows that get a null from the join

```
select *
  from products p
  left outer join (select *
                     from restriction
                    where (type = 'Not' and now() between start and end)
                       or (type = 'Only' and now() not between start and end)) r
                on (p.id = r.product_id)
 where r.product_id is null;
```

Comment: OK, so we are basically thinning out the restrictions before we join them in. Looks good! I will give it a try in the morning. Also, thanks for pointing out that BETWEEN exists, I had no idea!